# How can I make one function only run after a file has been written ? (node.js with excel.js library)

Tags: node.js, excel, asynchronous

MY file writes in the function convertfile() after formatworkbook() activates, therefore, throwing an error since the xlsxWorkbook variable does not exist until we've converted the file. I am new to async-await and promises but I did try to make it asynchronous (using both)

A couple of things I tried:

1) Trying to set it up to return the written file as a result of a promise (which using the .then keyword I still think I am doing a little) and then telling format workbook to await convertFile (declaring it as an async function)

2) Calling formatWorkbook within convertFile() after the then statement.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');
var Excel = require('exceljs');
const index = require("../routes/index")
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();

//var myworkbook = workbook.csv.readFile('uploads/HVACresultfile.csv')
// if no workbook await the file function should go here or something.


convertFile(workbook)



function convertFile(workbook) {
    var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    csvWorkbook = workbook.csv.readFile('uploads/HVACresultfile.csv')
    csvWorkbook.then(function(result){
    try {
    workbook.xlsx.writeFile('uploads/success.xlsx')
    console.log('converted')

    } catch(err){
    console.log(err)
    }
})

}

function formatWorkbook(workbook) {
    var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    var xlsxWorkbook = workbook.xlsx.readFile('uploads/success.xlsx')
    var xlsxWorksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('sheet1')

    xlsxWorkbook.then(function(result){
        try {
            assessFile(xlsxWorkbook,xlsxWorksheet)
            console.log('assessing')
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
}

function assessFile(workbook,xlsxWorkbook,xlsxWorksheet) {
    console.log('burf')
}


formatWorkbook()
```

running these functions would console.log assessing , burf and then converted. my ideal would of course to ensure that the file is converted first.

My ideal here is when this file is done , we read the file - perform multiple functions on it , and then write the file with the edits. What am I missing here?

ps. success.xlsx does write the CSV file as an xlsx correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the convertFile(workbook) call inside of the .then method of your formatWorkbook like this:

```
async function convertFile(workbook) {
    var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    csvWorkbook = workbook.csv.readFile('./products.xlsx')
    await csvWorkbook.then(async function(result){
        await workbook.xlsx.writeFile('./products2-teste-stack.xlsx').then( () => {
        console.log('converted')
        })

    })
}

function formatWorkbook(workbook) {
    var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    var xlsxWorkbook = workbook.xlsx.readFile('uploads/success.xlsx')
    var xlsxWorksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('sheet1')

    xlsxWorkbook.then(async function(result){
        try {
            // CALL CONVERT WHEN YOU FINISH READING YOUR FILE
            await convertFile(workbook)
            assessFile(xlsxWorkbook,xlsxWorksheet)
            console.log('assessing')
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
}
```

This way, it will not be called before you have finished reading your file.
If you convert your function to an async function you can await for the convertFile promise to resolve before executing the next lines of code.

Comment: The flow of operations if this 
1) CSV is uploaded
2) CSV should be converted to XLSX
3) I apply styles etc
4) XLSX is written with changes.

as it is, 'uploads/HVACresultfile.csv' will exist but 'uploads/success.xlsx' will not until convertFile() runs .

I THINK your answer is still correct, I just wanted to be sure because i am not sure I won't just get an error when we hit formatWorkbook()

Comment: OH NEVERMIND 

I think i Understand now

Comment: Await convertfile() will await the result of the full file conversion so the XLSX can exist. 

would it maybe be better to declare XLSX workbook after the try statement though?

Comment: No problem, Jason!! I add an async to your function so you can use an await on your promise.

Comment: You can keep inside so you can catch for any erros there!

Comment: I fix the place of the async function! It must be inside of your .then method, ok!

Comment: I will try running it as soon as I have a moment! Thank you!

Comment: Hi Jason! I changed the convertFile function to an async function so you can await there to read and write. This way those will happen first!

Comment: I did some things with async but I think I was missing a couple of things when actually trying to run it.. I didn't want to use setTimeout() either because it felt like a crude solution. Thanks!

As an aside, it's very interesting that I can put an async function into a synchronous function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190216/discussion-between-jason-harder-and-carlos-jafet-neto).

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this:

```
workbook.xlsx.readFile('uploads/success.xlsx').then(async function() {
    try {
        var xlsxWorksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('sheet1')
        await convertFile(xlsxWorksheet)
        assessFile(xlsxWorkbook,xlsxWorksheet)
        console.log('assessing')
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
})
```